# recyclerview radiobutton click event on activity kotlin using interfaces

Tags: kotlin, interface, android-recyclerview

Data Load in Recyclerview after Generated Click Event Item using Interface on 
Activity. code is below but Activity onItemCompanyClick is not execute.

How to Generate click event and get Value from the recyclerview using interfce.

MainActivity.kt

```
class Company : AppCompatActivity(),CompanyAdapter.Listner{

override fun onItemCompanyClick(company: Company) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked: ${company.Cmp_Name}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

CompanyAdapter.kt

```
class CompanyAdapter(private val listner :Listner, internal var companyList: List<Company>)
    :RecyclerView.Adapter<CompanyAdapter.CompanyViewHolder>()
{

    interface Listner {

        fun onItemCompanyClick(company: Company)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CompanyViewHolder {


        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item,p0,false)

        return CompanyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return companyList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CompanyViewHolder, p1: Int) {


       // p0.rbButton.text = this!!.companyList?.get(p1)?.Cmp_Name
        p0.bindModel(companyList[p1])
    }

    inner class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val radioButton : RadioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbCompanyName)

        fun bindModel(company: Company){

            radioButton.text = company.Cmp_Name
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is never called, you should call if when user click on your button.

Try something like:

MainActivity.kt

```
     class Company : AppCompatActivity(),CompanyAdapter.Listner{

       override fun onItemCompanyClick(company: Company){
Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked: ${company.Cmp_Name}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
 }
```

CompanyAdapter.kt

```
  class CompanyAdapter(private val listner :Listner, internal var companyList: List<Company>)
        :RecyclerView.Adapter<CompanyAdapter.CompanyViewHolder>()
    {
 interface Listner{
      fun onItemCompanyClick(company: Company)
    }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CompanyViewHolder {


            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item,p0,false)

            return CompanyViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {

            return companyList.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CompanyViewHolder, p1: Int) {


           // p0.rbButton.text = this!!.companyList?.get(p1)?.Cmp_Name
            p0.bindModel(companyList[p1])
        }

        inner class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

            val radioButton : RadioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbCompanyName)

            fun bindModel(company: Company){

                radioButton.text = company.Cmp_Name
                radioButton.setOnClickListener(_ -> listner.onItemCompanyClick(company))
            }
        }
    }
```

Also read [this guide about interface](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating), hope it helps.

Comment: radioButton.setOnClickListener(_ -> listner.onItemCompanyClick(company))

Comment: radiobutton value pass next activity